# RVM installing wrong Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I type `ruby -v` it tells me that it's version 1.9.3p484. Reinstalling it as version 2.2 still gives me 1.9.3, so how do I get version 2.2?

Comment: Are you issuing `rvm use 2.2` in your shell before `ruby -v`?

Comment: Yeah, it gives me an error saying something about enabling login shell.

Comment: You need to include `rvm` in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`. RVM will generally do it for you when you install it.

Comment: Yeah, it's there in my `.bashrc` file

Comment: And the `.zshrc` file

Comment: 1. Please post the exact error you get (login shell error) by editing your question.  ... and ...  2.Did you restart the terminal (on Ubuntu you might need to restart the computer) to allow the new settings to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into `.bash_profile`

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Open a new terminal a try again!